# Using OS X keychain with Git (locate command not helping)

Tags: git, macos, github

I am running OSX 10.10.

I am trying to cache my GitHub password in Git. I am currently following the instructions provided @ https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/. My OS X credential helper is already installed. I am running into an error installing the helper into the same directory where Git itself is installed.

Even though I have tried to use the locate command to locate my keychain, I am still receiving the "No such file or directory" error message. Here is what my terminal is returning:

```
$ locate git-credential-osxkeychain
/Applications/GitHub Desktop.app/Contents/Resources/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-osxkeychain
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/libexec/git-core/git-credential-osxkeychain
/usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain

$ sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain \ "/usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain"
mv: rename git-credential-osxkeychain to  /usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain: No such file or directory
```

Comment: I would leave the github application to interactive-use and install `git` via Macports or Homebrew.  That way you get a system that can keep itself updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the `git-credential-osxkeychain` binary already is in `/usr/local/git/bin/` - you shouldn't have to move it there.

Please try the following:

First verify whether `git-credential-osxkeychain` is already on your path by running

```
which git-credential-osxkeychain
```

If the binary is on your path, it will print the location, e.g. `/usr/local/git/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain`

If it prints the path, then you should be able to configure git to use it:

```
git config --global credential.helper osxkeychain
```

If the `which` command does not find the `git-credential-osxkeychain` binary, you need to move it to a directory on your path, or add the `/usr/local/git/bin` to your $PATH variable.