# VSTS - allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token in Release Management

Tags: oauth, build, azure-devops

In VSTS/VSO is it possible to gain access to the OAuth token from release management?  The option is there in Build but I do not see it available from release.  The url below suggests that it's been implement but the comments suggests otherwise.

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/12980961-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-in-release-man

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Found it.  First need to add a task for an environment.  Once the task is added you can click on "Run on agent".  This will open a a different view not available through oan of the tabs.  Expand "Additional options" and check "Allow scripts to access OAuth token".

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. All other docs I found say that that setting is in the build definition's "Options" tab, but it is as per this answer.

Comment: Update from 2023 - this is still valid :) and in the same place on Azure DevOps

Answer (score 26):

In my case, this option is on *Build & Realese* / *Task* / *Phase (Run on Agent)* / *Allow scripts to access OAuth token*

[image]

or
[image]

Please Find of attachment

Comment: The most relevant for my case.

Comment: Same for me, the official docs don't match the screenshot.