# Authenticate Azure Pipelines Powershell task against Azure DevOps Rest API

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

### Requirements

My requirement is that for my Azure devops release pipeline I want to tag a specific commit with an annotated tag which contains the build number and the date (which is auto-set on an annotated tag).

### Proposed solution

My solution to this is to use a the Azure Powershell pipeline task, the one shown here:
[image]

The task (ignore what's in the script box right now) will use the Azure Subscription that I have set in order to authenticate towards the Azure DevOps REST API. I have successfully been able to perform the task I want using a personal access token (PAT) but this is not stable long-term for a whole team and I want to use our Azure Subscription.

### The problem

My problem is that I'm not sure how to use the authentication of the Azure Subscription correctly. I seem to get some data using Get-AzureRmContext (see current code below) and then I found [a GitHub issue which seems to do sort of the same thing](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/2494). The code gets some kind of OAuth token but using the code below, Azure still returns to me that I need to sign in, so I assume it's not the correct token. I don't understand how things hatch into each other.

Note that my subscription should have all the permissions it needs to do what I want.

### Code so far:

```
Function Get-AccessToken($tenantId) {
    $cache = [Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.TokenCache]::DefaultShared
    $cacheItem = $cache.ReadItems() | Where-Object { $_.TenantId -eq $tenantId } | Select-Object -First 1
    return $cacheItem.AccessToken
}

$context = Get-AzureRmContext
$uri = "https://dev.azure.com/<my_org>/<my_area>/_apis/git/repositories/<project_sha>/annotatedtags?api-version=5.0-preview.1"
$token = Get-AccessToken $context.tenantID

$body = @"
{
    "taggedObject": {
        "objectId": "$(BUILD.SOURCEVERSION)"
    },
    "name": "D-$(Build.BuildNumber)",
    "message": "dummy"
}
"@
$header = @{"Authorization" = "Bearer" + $token}

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers $header
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: i was under the impression you dont need to auth to ADO from inside the job?

Comment: @4c74356b41 You don't? If I don't specify any authorization header then I get a sign-in html page in response

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004090/vsts-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-in-release-management

Comment: Wow, thanks man. That was way simpler than what I tried...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VSTS - allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token in Release Management](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41004090/vsts-allow-scripts-to-access-oauth-token-in-release-management)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the example for the build tasks: [Use a PowerShell script to customize your build pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/powershell?view=azure-devops)

1. You have to enable access to token (option **Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token**)

[image]

2. Then use it in your script. Script from the example:

   `$url = "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI)$env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID/_apis/build/definitions/$($env:SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID)?api-version=5.0"`

   `Write-Host "URL: $url"`
   `$pipeline = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{
       Authorization = "Bearer $env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN"
   }`

   `Write-Host "Pipeline = $($pipeline | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100)"`