# Use git or hg repository tag as version in Azure Pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, versioning

I want to build a project in Azure Pipelines, but I want to know what the idiomatic way is to obtain the latest tag, latest tag distance, and repo remote path/URL in order to pass those values into the actual build script that is inside the repository.

Previously our build script would invoke `hg log -r . --template` with a clever template, but we found when moving to Continua CI build server that the build agent doesn't have access to the actual repository during a build, and had to find another way.

I'm assuming the same issue would crop up with Azure Pipelines and haven't quite found the relevant docs yet on artifact versioning.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like this answer contains all the info you need: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38731565/274535.

Comment: Not really; I don't want to execute hg or git commands during the build (because in Continua and Azure Pipelines the actual repository folder isn't present during the build), I want to find out how the tool decides what version it is building, and how it communicates that to the build agents doing the actual build.

Comment: Hmm, I thought Azure Pipelines build agent has the actual Git repo during the build, that's why the Git commands are possible... That Microsoft document referenced in the thread above contains samples of PowerShell build task which runs Git commands

Answer (score 0):

For git at least, Azure Pipelines does a full clone of the repo by default, unless you explicitly denote that you're doing a shallow clone (source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/pipeline-options-for-git?view=azure-devops).

Deriving the version/tag can be done via normal git commands (i.e. git describe --tags or whatever you prefer), which can then be saved as VSO variables to be accessed in later steps in the same job (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-using-expressions for more info on how to do that).