# Is there any way to send release pipeline data to GIT repo in devops?

Tags: azure, github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-task, azure-git-deployment

Is there any task or something which will send the release pipeline data to git repo instead of sending it to any evironment?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Invoke [HTTP REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/http-rest-api?view=azure-devops) task to call github api and [`create a file`](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#create-a-file) there.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not.

The only way you could do is running git commands in a release to git push files/data.

How to do this, you could refer below links:

- [Executing git commands inside a build job in Visual Studio Team Services (was VSO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670306/executing-git-commands-inside-a-build-job-in-visual-studio-team-services-was-vs)
- [Run Git commands in a script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)