# Can't switch my git bash accounts

Tags: git, bash

I wanted to practice using my git bash but could switch accounts.

When I type `git config user.name` what should I put here?
And what about `git config user.email`?

Don't I need to type my password anywhere? That's kinda weird. So the problem is that I can't push changes using my second account, I got this error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (permission denied)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com
```

Have I changed my account or not? I don't understand that.
How can I switch accounts correctly?

Answer (score 0):

`user.name` and `user.email` have nothing to do with authentication (only with commit authorship: see "[Why are my commits linked to the wrong user?](https://help.github.com/articles/why-are-my-commits-linked-to-the-wrong-user/)")

All you need to do to "switch account" is modify your remote url

```
 git remote set-url origin https://<secondGitHubAccount>@github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

That will work as long as `secondGitHubAccount` is an owner or collaborator of `<repo>`.

You can use a git credential helper to cache your password (and avoid having to enter it for *each* Git remote operations). For instance, on Windows, you would use the [manager helper](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) (see "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)").