# Mapped git files losts their connection

Tags: git, bitbucket

I got a project from remote Git repo. But after New Year I has only there local copies and no Git connection.
My actions were:
1. git remote add origin 
2. git remote -v    shows me what I want
3. git checkout 
4. git fetch     AND THIS it shows me

> You do not have permission to access Bitbucket. Please contact your
>   administrator to resolve this issue.

But I can can navigate it with my browser. Whats the problem - tell me plz.

Yesss. not git fetch shows me all remote branches. THen the situation - i'm in branch **origin/aaaa**
and want to update it from server (as rebase) - soo

> $ git pull
>   There is no tracking information for the current branch.
>   Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
>   See git-pull(1) for details.
>       git pull  
>       If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:
>       git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/ aaaa

Ok I can do

```
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/aaaa aaaa
```

Maybe it starts to work - and what with other branches - hoew to link all my local branches to remote repo - only one by one?

Comment: Your stored Git credentials might be wrong or outdated.

Comment: Did you visit the repository's web page on BitBucket? Could it possible have moved? Verify that the repo URL given on the site is the same as you entered in Step 1. Or if this was a private repo, could it be possible that credentials expired or were revoked? Could have been a year-end clean up task of some sort at BitBucket or by the repo owner.

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one. Your edit was answered a long time ago with http://stackoverflow.com/a/6300386/6309

Answer (score 1):

1. The first problem that IntellJ IDEA 2016.3.x can't execute [VCS - Git - Remotes...]. You need do it in console with **git remote add...**
2. The second problem was that Windows doesn't use my saved credentials from [Control Panel - Users - Credentials - Edit]. So I just remove'em and recreate - so fetch starts to work.
3. The third was, that was create new branch, but noone tols me about it :(

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `git config credential helper` (for instance, on Windows, you could see "manager"

If that is the case, see "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)":

```
git credential-manager delete <url>
```

Here

```
git credential-manager delete https://github.com
```

Or you can [access the interface of the manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39592537/6309).

You don't have to remove the credential helper which is practical for caching user's password.

Comment: Ok. Now I clear my creadentials for stash. And now - when I try to fetch - I get "Fetch failed: unable to access '': Couldn't resolve host ''. May be I need to add it somewhere - Git doesn't ask me for my log/pass automaticly?

Comment: @R1K0 what is the beginning of this url? (to check if it is an https or ssh one)