# error 403: can't push to my github account

Tags: github

I am getting next error:

```
$ git push -u origin master
remote: Permission to teddyruns/medals.git denied to franciswebdevelopment
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/teddyruns/medals.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

I have checked my global user name and email, and created a new ssh key, but `franciswebdevelopment` is my old account,

I have no idea why I can't push to my new account,

Does anybody have any idea where I am going wrong?

Comment: Did you check you haven't set up an entry in `~/.ssh/config`?

Comment: Have you added the SSH key to the SSH agent,and ensured that the public key is on Github?

Comment: Thanks for your answers! How do i get to see the entries in .ssh?

Comment: Your remote is configured to use https protocol, you should probably change it to git protocol, if you want to use ssh keys.

Answer (score 1):

> but `franciswebdevelopment` is my old account

That means you probably have a git crendential helper which has cached the credentials `franciswebdevelopment` for github.com.

```
git config credential.helper
```

If that is the case, [remove that entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41712167/6309):

```
git credential-manager delete https://github.com
```

Then try again (but not right now, with HTTPS or SSH, because [GitHub is experiencing a major outage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52922466/6309))

Answer (score -1):

Github is currently experiencing issues,

Click [here](https://status.github.com/messages) to check their status.

Comment: I did mention it in my answer, but the issue experienced by the OP is not directly related to that outage: it is a *local* credential caching issue.