# Windows 10 Git push said everything is up to date but changes are not made

Tags: git

I am using MINGW64 to push my changes to a remote repository. When I make a new change I add it and commit. When I push it said it made the changes then I go to github and the changes weren't made. This is happening when I push from my mac and my desktop. I also tried going to the site and doing it manually and that didn't work. Nothing works any help would be great!

Comment: Add the output of `git remote -v` to your question. Also, what does `git log -1` show?

Comment: You're missing something :(  SUGGESTION: 1) Use git bash.  2) `git status`.  3) `git remote -v`.  4) Change something (e.g. modify a file). 5) `git add .`.  6) `git -m "test update" commit`.  7) `git push origin`.  8) Log on to your remote repo to check if the "push" updated the remote repo.  9) `git log | head`.  10) Copy/paste the results (including your Git bash commands and Git responses) into your question.

Comment: I think you're working in a different branch, but Github is showing the `master` branch by default. Do your changes appear in other branches on github?

Comment: Hey guys, I guess Github just lagged because my push took effect a couple hours later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, your changes *cannot* be successfully pushed to GitHub.

GitHub is experiencing a [major outage](https://status.github.com/messages):

[image: outage]

That is why any push or direct modification through the GitHub website does not work.