# Bitbucket Git Push Error

Tags: git, ssh, bitbucket, git-push

After I changed password for my bitbucket account, I can't seem to push anything to the repository. I can pull, add, commit but not push.

I used to clone using https and whenever I push, it would say

```
Remote: unauthorized Fatal: Authentication failed for url.
```

I search for this on google and stack overflow for 2 days, none of the solution worked.

So I decided to try SSH. I follow instruction to generate an SSH-Key and add it to bitbucket.
However as soon as I push it gave me:

```
repository access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists."
```

[image: pic here]

Any idea on what to do?

Comment: Please show us the public key you've submitted to bitbucket (screenshot preferred), your local `id_rsa.pub` (not `id_rsa`!) from `~/.ssh`. These are both public keys.

Comment: When you added the SSH key to Bitbucket, did you also update the remote URL from HTTPS to SSH?

Comment: @JimRedmond Yes, I did change it to SSH. My remote is git@bitbucket.org:path/projectname.

Comment: @mszymborski link to the SSH public key https://postimg.cc/image/os4no7du3/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding https, double-check if you have a credential helper which would have cached your credentials:

```
git config credential.helper
```

As explained in "[How to sign out in Git Bash console in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)", this would remove the credentials:

```
git credential-manager delete https://bitbucket.org
```

Regarding ssh, double-check your key is proposed with:

```
set GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -v"
git push
```

Comment: I am at Mac and tried the equivalent of it and it didn't work.

Comment: @ParkLee OK, but did `git config credential.helper` returned anything?

Comment: It returned osxkeychain

Comment: @ParkLee Then removing the credentials as in https://help.github.com/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain/ will help, but only if your remote URL (git remote -v) is an https one, not an ssh one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a wild guess: you're on macOS version 10.12 or later, right?

Apple changed the behavior of ssh-agent as of Sierra so that it no longer adds keys automatically. You can change this in one of several ways:

- Add `ssh-add -A` to your .rc file (usually .bashrc, sometimes something else). This will add identities from your keychain to the ssh-agent. (You can add identities to the keychain with `ssh-add -K`.)
- Update ~/.ssh/config to include something like this:

`Host bitbucket.org
     IdentityFile /path/to/private/key
     AddKeysToAgent yes`

(The SSH config file is a powerful tool, but different systems may have different options. Read `man ssh_config` to see which options you have available on a given system.)