# Not able to pull-push after changing user

Tags: git, github

I am not able to pull and push after changing my user on git. Previously, I have access to repo with a username say **ABC**, then removed that user access and given access to my other user **XYZ**.

But after that, I am not able to pull and push anything in that repo. I have already tried several options like setting upstream, setting origin and all.

This is the error I am receiving:

```
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/something/something.git/' not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If GitHub responds with a "not found" error, that means:

- either the URL isn't exactly right (like uppercase/lowercase error in it)
- or it is a private repository, and the user automatically associated with that URL is not the right one.

In the second case, check your git config credential.helper: if set, that means your old user credential might still be cached for that URL.
You need to remove that entry from your credential helper ([example for Windows here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/6309), or: [`git credential-manager reject https://github.com/something/something.git`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309) )

Then your next push will ask you the credentials again: this time, enter the *new* user.