# WebStorm JetBrains IDE using wrong GitHub account to push code, giving me a 403 forbidden error

Tags: git, github, version-control, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm trying to push my code to GitHub from the WebStorm IDE. It keeps giving me

```
remote: Permission to dagu-games/dagu.git denied to [USERNAME].
fatal: unable to access 'https://dagu-games@github.com/dagu-games/dagu.git/':
       The requested URL returned error: 403
```

as the error, where `[USERNAME]` is an old, unused user I must have logged into at some point.

I can't find a reference to this user anywhere when I search it on my PC or when I look in any configuration files.
I've examined the local config file and the global `.gitconfig` file and there are no references to `[USERNAME]` anywhere.

I have added the user that owns the GitHub repository so it definitely has permission.
I also have the IDE logged into the correct user and it is set as the default account.

It basically looks like I am logged into the correct account everywhere and with no trace of the old account anywhere, but when I go to push my code, it errors out saying I am trying to do it as this old username.

Is there some place I'm not looking that has me still logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some place I'm not looking that has me still logged in?

Possible your git credential helper, which could have cached the wrong user/credentials associated to that URL.

```
git config credential helper
```

On [Windows, for instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39608906/6309), you can [remove it with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309):

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com/dagu-games/dagu.git
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for me. I simply needed to delete the credential in the Windows Credential Manager. I didn't even know that existed.