# Git doesn't allow me to enter my password for cloning since I got it wrong the first time

Tags: git, git-clone

I ran the command once, and got a pop-up that said I needed to enter my username and password, I then did not enter the right one, and now the window to enter in the username and password doesn't show up

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>git clone https://gitlab.com/group/project.git
Cloning into 'project'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.com/group/project.git/'
```

Is there some way for me to redo this, so that I can enter the username and 
password once again?

Comment: Try `git clone https://username@gitlab.com/group/project.git` and see if a password is asked. If not, try `git clone https://username:password@gitlab.com/group/project.git`

Comment: Looks like you need to reset the `Windows Git Credential Manager`. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15382950/5698740) answer might help you

Answer (score 1):

As I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309), with a recent Git, try:

```
git credential-manager reject https://gitlab.com
```

That should reset the cached credentials, and the next clone should request them again.

If the command is not available, try again with a simplified PATH:

```
set PATH=C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
set GH=C:\path\to\git
set PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%PATH%
```