# Git bash doesn't allow me to re-enter my password

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have my own private repo in Github. I used GitBash to clone it to my local computer and accidentally entered a wrong password. Then I tried again and what I had was

```
fatal: could not create work tree dir 'sample': Permission denied
```

I tried this command

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

as described here [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git/15382950#15382950) but it didn't help.

I tried this command

```
git credential-manager delete https://github.com
```

as described here [Git doesn't allow me to enter my password for cloning since I got it wrong the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756004/git-doesnt-allow-me-to-enter-my-password-for-cloning-since-i-got-it-wrong-the-f) but it says "Unknown command 'delete'. Please use `git-credential-manager ?` to display help."

I don't know how to make it forget what I entered, or enter credentials again.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git

Comment: Yes, I saw, and it's the first link in my post.

Comment: Oh, shame on me. Haven't clicked it :/ Recognized that the information in there are pretty outdated. Back to your issue - I assume you are on windows reading GitBash, am I right? Another stupid question maybe, but if delete failed, have you tried *remove* like `git credential-manager remove https://github.com`? And, have you checked the credential manager in the windows control panel?

Comment: @Christian, no I didn't try. Let me try the next time when it happens again. I solved this problem just waiting for 5 minutes or so.

Answer (score 0):

> but it says "Unknown command 'delete'.

As I [mention here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309), the proper command now is **`reject`**:

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com
```

Comment: You refer to Git 2.9.2 => GCM 1.5.0. Then, my version must differ. Thanks for the hint.