# How do I log in using the Git terminal?

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to sign in using the Git command line, so that I can push my changes to a repository I have. I usually use a different account to the one I'm trying to use right now, and pushing works fine on there. The terminal is the one integrated into Visual Studio Code, and it is Git Bash.

What I want to do is sign into this different account and then push from that account. I remember at one point there was a popup with a login box on it. How would I get this to show up again?

So far, I have tried using the commands:

`git config user.name my-name`
`git config user.email my-email`

Which don't appear to have asked for any credentials. Upon Googling (just now) it appears that they are used just to set my commit username.

So how do I log in from the Git command line? I've been stuck on this for ages and I feel like there's probably a really simple solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In github or VSTS you need to generate token and you will use it as password.your email address will be username.

Comment: @AnirudhaGupta Is that an SSH key? I was trying to use HTTPS but if that's easier then I'll just do that.

Comment: You are not specifying on which host you are trying to push. Git is just a _stupid content tracker_, It looks like your issue has more to do with something like BitBucket, Github, GitLab... rather than Git.

Comment: I did use same method in windows and mac, it's adding SSH key itself for me. Try it, it might work for you as well.

Comment: As you mention in Q that it's not telling for password, clone the repos and it will tell you to enter authentication.

Answer (score 34):

Just entering your user in the command line won't work for newer versions of git. To sign in to GitHub, you'll need to download GitHub CLI, then do `gh auth login`

Comment: Do `git push` and `git pull` operations use the `gh auth login` you have done? I thought this would only be effective for future `gh` operations, not for future `git` operations.

Comment: Yes, if you use ```gh auth login``` it will login to your account and you will be able to use git with your account as well. I tried it. I use this method all the time as I have to push and pull to my private repos

Comment: Oh, that is super cool. I will have to test that feature.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, just `winget install --id GitHub.cli` and  `gh auth login` worked, but you have to close your terminal and re-open to try again.

Answer (score 7):

`user.name` & `user.email` have nothing to do with the server communication - they are used only when committing. If you use HTTP to access your repo, then add another remote with your new username in the URL:

```
git remote add origin2 https://new_username@host.com/repo
```

And then push/fetch using the new remote:

```
git push origin2 branch_name
```

Windows will recognize that the URL has new username and will ask for your creds.

You can also use SSH. Generate the key, upload the public one to your Git Server under the right account, set up `.ssh/config` to use that key. Though you still will need either to add new remote or re-point the existing one to switch to SSH protocol.

### Git Credential Manager

Another option (as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549834/how-do-i-sign-out-in-the-git-bash-console-in-windows/38553149#38553149)) that's available since 2018 is to `git credential-manager erase <url>`. Though personally I didn't test it.

Comment: `git credential-manager reject` would actually sign the user **out**, but it has since been changed to `erase`. Documentation about command line usage is available on the project's [github page](https://github.com/git-ecosystem/git-credential-manager/blob/release/docs/usage.md).

Comment: Updated to `erase`

Answer (score 6):

1. To authenticate on Windows, use this command to install GitHub CLI:

   `winget install --id GitHub.cli`

For more information on other OS, visit https://github.com/cli/cli#installation

2. After installation, you may have to restart your code editor if you are using its terminal. Then,

   `gh auth login`

Supply the necessary info and you're logged in. This worked for me

Comment: Isn't it `gh auth login`?

Comment: @Daniel thanks for spotting that

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link to the documentation that explains how to login to github using a variety of methods.
https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/about-authentication-to-github

If you are using a Mac you may also have to remove any cached credentials.
https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain

Answer (score 1):

this link will work [How can I save username and password in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git/35942890#35942890)

Run

```
git config --global credential.helper store
```

then

```
git pull
```

provide a username and password and those details will then be remembered later. The credentials are stored in a file on the disk, with the disk permissions of "just user readable/writable" but still in plaintext.

If you want to change the password later

```
git pull
```

Will fail, because the password is incorrect, git then removes the offending user+password from the `~/.git-credentials` file, so now re-run

```
git pull
```

to provide a new password so it works as earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal:

> `gh auth login`
> You will see these **if gh is not installed already**

```
Command 'gh' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo snap install gh  # version 2.6.0-15-g1a10fd5a, or
sudo apt  install gh  # version 2.27.0+dfsg1-1build1
See 'snap info gh' for additional versions.
```

Then:

> `sudo apt  install gh`

After that follow the prompts until you are promotes to login with your browser `highly prefered`. Once authenticated, you will be all set.