# Why does Git not recognize origin and how can I correct this to update the remote.origin.url with a personal token?

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

I have a private remote repository on GitHub that I'm trying to push to production on our AWS server (using Ubuntu). I've tried the following commands and received the following errors:

```
sudo git pull

remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git/'


sudo git remote -v 

origin  https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git (fetch)
origin  https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git (push)


sudo git remote rm origin 

fatal: No such remote: 'origin'


sudo git config --list 

user.name=project_username
remote.origin.url=https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true


sudo git remote set-url origin https://project_username:NEW_PERSONAL_TOKEN@github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git

fatal: No such remote 'origin'
```

Why does Git not recognize `origin` and how can I correct this to update the `remote.origin.url`?

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`?

Answer (score 1):

You removed origin with

```
git remote rm origin
```

So no wonder it doesn't exist anymore and you can't do anything with it. You can add it back by:

```
git remote add origin [address]
```

The original error says that you shouldn't use HTTPS with Basic Auth. You should either generate a personal token and put it into URL or use ssh address (and use public-key auth):

```
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
remote: Please see https://github.blog/2020-12-15-token-authentication-requirements-for-git-operations/ for more information.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git/'
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I tried it and this is what I'm seeing: 

sudo git remote add origin https://project_username:NEW_PERSONAL_TOKEN@github.com/...

sudo git remote -v 
origin  https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/... (fetch)
origin  https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/... (push)
origin  https://project_username:NEW_PERSONAL_TOKEN@github.com/... (push)

sudo git config --list
user.name=project_username
remote.origin.url=https://project_username:OLD_PASSWORD@github.com/...

It looks to me like origin using OLD_PASSWORD is still the remote.

Comment: Ah, so you re-create origin but the URL stays old? Do you see old values in `.git/config` file?

Comment: Correct, the URL stays old. No, I actually see the new values in .git/config.

Comment: Could you try to `--unset` those properties and re-add origin again?

Comment: Also, if you use Windows, try this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947268/how-do-i-log-in-using-the-git-terminal/57947653#57947653

Comment: Thanks for your help! I realized I was making changed locally but the old URL was set globally and was able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the answer: I realized the issue was that the `remote.origin.url` was set *globally* with `OLD_PASSWORD` but *locally* as `NEW_PERSONAL_TOKEN.`

This is what worked:
Using `sudo git config --global --edit` to edit the global config file directly.

Comment: Dear @krfreder, thank you for the answer. Running the `sudo git config --global --edit` did open the config file, containing user name and email tags. However, I was not sure how to proceed with `remote.origin.url`. Would it be hard for you to add an example? Much appreciated :)

Comment: @CuriousWatcher - you can find the command in my original post but I'll add it down here for you: `sudo git remote set-url origin https://project_username:NEW_PERSONAL_TOKEN@github.com/projectrepo/projectname.git`  I also found this post helpful in understanding my issue - [How do I show my global git configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12254076/how-do-i-show-my-global-git-configuration). And this documentation in understanding the `git remote` command - [Git docs, git remote](https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-remote)