# Github clone wiki "not found'

Tags: github, wiki

How do you clone a Github wiki.

The several times I've copied to command from our repo and attempted to clone locally..

`git clone https://github.com/[orgname]/[name].wiki.git`

I get this error:
fatal: repository `git clone https://github.com/[orgname]/[name].wiki.git` not found

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why it isn't working with the HTTPS, but I changed it to:
`git clone git@github.com:devforce/trailmaker.wiki.git`
and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If it does not work with HTTPS, but works with SSH, it is possible:

- the repository is a private one
- the wrong credentials are cached (check `git config --global credential.helper`: you might need to [remove the credential associated to `github.com`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58361327/6309))
- the right GitHub user is identified through an SSH URL because of the default ~/.ssh/id_rsa private key whose public key is correctly registered.

A wrong authentication would generate a 404 (as a security best practice to avoid confirming the existence of a user when bad credentials are provided)