# Removing github credential from a mac

Tags: git, macos, github

I have read a tons of topic about how to remove credential from a mac, and the most repetitive answer is "remove credential from native keychain".

It doesn't work, event if I remove github credential from keychain, after "git push" something is adding automatically again my credential to keychain.

What can be wrong ? And how to finally remove my password and email from a mac ?

Comment: Note: macOS is UNIX, not Linux.

Comment: How were the keys generated? Did you remove `~/.ssh`? Also, this is not very secure - an ext recovery program will recover the keys easily. You need to remove them from the GitHub account.

Comment: @Qix-MONICAWASMISTREATED I'm using https, not ssh

Comment: You tagged your question with Linux. I removed that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `credential helper` directly to erase the keychain entry.

To do this, type the following command:

```
$ git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com
protocol=https
> [Press Return]
```

If it's successful, nothing will print out.

[**Github documentation**](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)

Comment: I tried this, but then `git config --list` still returns my git credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Git 2.42 (Q3 2023) suggests and documents `git credential reject`:

See [commit 6c26da8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c26da8404c8acfed62fa4775b7b591f099bcd33), [commit aeb21ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeb21ce22eec112b37975443a160cb5418c6ec22) (15 Jun 2023) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5ee8fcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ee8fcdabc25ade1f8c5295575a1c20ab4f6f347), 23 Jun 2023)</sup>

> ### [`credential`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6c26da8404c8acfed62fa4775b7b591f099bcd33): erase all matching credentials
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>

> `credential reject` sends the erase action to each helper, but the exact behaviour of `erase` isn't specified in documentation or tests.
> Some helpers (such as `credential-store` and `credential-libsecret`) delete all matching credentials, others (such as `credential-cache`) delete at most one matching credential.
>
> Test that helpers erase all matching credentials.
> This behaviour is easiest to reason about.
> Users expect that `echo "url=https://example.com" | git credential reject` or `echo "url=https://example.com\nusername=tim" | git credential reject` erases *all* matching credentials.
>
> Fix credential-cache.

`git credential` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6c26da8404c8acfed62fa4775b7b591f099bcd33/Documentation/git-credential.txt#L42):

> If the action is `reject`, `git-credential` will send the description to any configured credential helpers, which may erase any stored credentials matching the description.

---

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023) updates two credential helpers to correctly match which credential to erase; they dropped not the ones with stale password.

See [commit cb626f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb626f8e5cb76ce081ab0a02656611f05a54cfb5), [commit 7144dee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7144dee3ec233674ba534797e41fa399708c8313) (26 Jul 2023) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bc92d2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc92d2c7ac6bd85f2447dbc37c886a4e72076005), 28 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`credential/libsecret`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7144dee3ec233674ba534797e41fa399708c8313): erase matching creds only
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>

> The credential erase request typically includes protocol, host, username and password.
>
> credential-libsecret erases a stored credential if it matches protocol, host and username, regardless of password.
>
> This is confusing in the case the stored password differs from that in the request.
> This case can occur when multiple credential helpers are configured.
>
> Only erase credential if stored password matches request (or request omits password).
>
> This fixes test "helper (`libsecret`) does not erase a password distinct from input" when t0303 is run with `GIT_TEST_CREDENTIAL_HELPER` set to "libsecret".
> This test was added in [aeb21ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeb21ce22eec112b37975443a160cb5418c6ec22) ("`credential`: avoid erasing distinct password", 2023-06-13, Git v2.42.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ee8fcdabc25ade1f8c5295575a1c20ab4f6f347) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ff334181cfb6485d3ba50843038209a2a253907)).

---

With Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), update two credential helpers to correctly match which credential to erase; they dropped not the ones with stale password.

See [commit cb626f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cb626f8e5cb76ce081ab0a02656611f05a54cfb5), [commit 7144dee](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7144dee3ec233674ba534797e41fa399708c8313) (26 Jul 2023) by [M Hickford (`hickford`)](https://github.com/hickford).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bc92d2c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bc92d2c7ac6bd85f2447dbc37c886a4e72076005), 28 Aug 2023)</sup>

> ### [`credential/libsecret`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7144dee3ec233674ba534797e41fa399708c8313): erase matching creds only
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: M Hickford</sup>

> The credential erase request typically includes protocol, host, username and password.
>
> `credential-libsecret` erases a stored credential if it matches protocol, host and username, regardless of password.
>
> This is confusing in the case the stored password differs from that in the request.
> This case can occur when multiple credential helpers are configured.
>
> Only erase credential if stored password matches request (or request omits password).
>
> This fixes test "helper (libsecret) does not erase a password distinct from input" when `t0303` is run with `GIT_TEST_CREDENTIAL_HELPER` set to "libsecret".
> This test was added in [aeb21ce](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aeb21ce22eec112b37975443a160cb5418c6ec22) ("`credential`: avoid erasing distinct password", 2023-06-13, Git v2.42.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5ee8fcdabc25ade1f8c5295575a1c20ab4f6f347) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6ff334181cfb6485d3ba50843038209a2a253907)).