# Push to GitHub *with* Username and Password only

Tags: git, github, ssh, bitbucket

I work on a lot of machines and most of them are not mine. So, these machines are already set up with the `ssh-key` to those guy's GitHub account. Now, I want to work on that machine and then push the code to my GitHub account. But when trying to do so I get a warning saying remote: **Permission to mukul/repo.git denied to *NewUser*** .
`The requested URL returned error: 403`

I know that I can set-up these machines with my GitHub account, but I guess that's not feasible (at least not ideal). I tried googling but it seems to filled with the posts answering the question of how to get rid of username and password thing i.e setting up ssh-key for smooth development experience.

But I want the GitHub to ask me for the username and password. As a quick fix, I tried to locally change the git config for that repo, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: I had a similar question which turns out to be duplicate of some other question :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68794860/i-can-login-to-github-with-my-username-and-password-but-can-not-push-code-with-t

Comment: @iRestMyCaseYourHonor yeah GitHub has deprecated authentication based on username and password :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I want the GitHub to ask me for the username and password.

Then use an HTTPS URL instead of an SSH one (which would be default authentication with the ~/.ssh/id_rsa existing private SSH keys, registered to the other GitHub account)

Make sure your `git config credential.helper` is empty, or, if it is not ([for instance, on Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40312117/6309)), check if the credentials are already cached.

For osxkeychain, follow "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)".
Or, as [I explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58178308/6309):

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but I'm already using the https URL and also `git remote get-url origin` show the https url.

Comment: @codeitup Then what `git config credential.helper` returns?

Comment: its `osxkeychain`

Comment: this command requires the password stored in KeyChain to be saved somewhere else as this command erases the password for github.com... and saves the most recent password and username . In the current situation I'm being choosy Thanks for answer, it helped!

Comment: @codeitup Yes, this credential helper would store only one password for a given address.