# I can login to github with my username and password but can not push code with them using HTTPs

Tags: git, github, https

I can login to github using my `username` and `password`. I recently cloned one of my repos using HTTPS and did a change. However, when I want to push:

- I am shown the prompt `Username for 'https://github.com':` . I write my username. Then it asks for `Password for 'https://username@github.com':`. But my username is not `https://username@github.com':`. It is `username`. Anyways, it does not work when I use the same `password` and `username` that I used during logging in to github.
- My config has the line in the form of `remote.origin.url=https://github.com/username/some-repo.git` . It's as it was when I cloned the first time using HTTPS.
- I already tried adding `https://username@github.com/username/some-repo.git` . It is no different than providing the `username` in prompt. It somehow still thinks that my username is `https://username@github.com`.

I don't understand why this is always an issue for me and I always switch to using SSH despite that HTTPS is the default way. In my opinion there should be a way to use HTTPS not only for cloning the repo but also pushing afterwards. I always had an issue and opted in an ad-hoc solution and never solved this due to my laziness, but here I am going the extra mile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Github has removed the option to use a username-password combination.

https://github.blog/changelog/2021-08-12-git-password-authentication-is-shutting-down/

You should switch to ssh instead which is much better