# Permission to username/project.git denied to user

Tags: git, github

I created repo on the GitHub remote, cloned it on the local.
I configured Git username and email using:

```
git config --local user.name "firstname lastname"
git config --local user.email "first.last@gmail.com"
```

*git remote show origin* is also giving the correct upstream
But when I add files, commit and try to push using:

```
git push origin master
```

I am getting error as:

```
remote: Permission to username/project.git denied to randomuser.
```

I don't know from where the ***randomuser*** is coming from. When I do: `git config --list --local` I am getting the correct username and email. I need help to figure out how it is happening and how to overcome it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The username/email set in Git has nothing to do with *authentication* on GitHub, and is only used for commit authorship.

It depends on your remote origin URL: SSH (`git@github.com:...`) or HTTPS (`https://github.com/...`)

In the former case, check your `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` keys.

In the latter case, check our `git config credential.helper` output: the credentials manager could cache the wrong credentials ("`randomuser`" for `github.com`).

If it is "`manager`", you can "[sign out in the Git Bash console in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)".

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com
```

On Mac, for `osxkeychain`, see "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)"

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

Then try again: it will prompt for user GitHub username/password.

Answer (score 0):

A very quick solution I found was * I am using macOS btw *, I went to the keychain, searched GitHub, deleted all of those saved passwords, and then returned to the terminal and re-entered the command.

Problem was solved.