# How to prevent git from automatically using other account?

Tags: git

I used have a "work" GitHub account.

Everything works fine, and I have no trouble pushing code etc to my work account.

Then I created a personal Github account to use for my personal portfolio on GitHub pages.
When I try to push to my personal account, I get the error:

```
Permission to
mypersonalaccountusername/mypersonalaccountusername.github.io.git
denied to mycompanyusername
```

I expected git to ask me for my username, but somehow it assumes that I am trying to push with my company username. No idea what's going on.
Github Desktop is signed into `mycompanyusername`, but for my personal Git repository I am trying to push from the terminal by doing:

```
git push -u origin master
```

So how can I push to my personal repository from my personal account instead of my company account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on your remote origin URL: SSH (`git@github.com:...`) or HTTPS (`https://github.com/...`), used by GitHub Desktop.

- for SSH: check your `~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub)` keys (if the public key is registered to your first account, said account will be used).
- In the latter case, check our `git config credential.helper` output: the credentials manager could cache the wrong credentials ("`mycompanyusername`" for `github.com`).

If it is "`manager`", you can "[sign out in the Git Bash console in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)".

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com
```

On Mac, for `osxkeychain`, see "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)"

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

Then try again: it will prompt for user GitHub username/password.