# Git push uses the wrong credentials

Tags: git

I just `git clone` one of my repository with:

```
git clone https://github.com/org/repo.git
cd repo
vi ...
git commit -am "things"
git push 
remote: Permission to org/repo.git denied to nowox.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/org/repo.git/': 
The requested 
URL returned error: 403
```

Curiously I do not have this `nowox` user configured on this PC. The proof is:

```
git config --list | grep nowox
```

Also in this repository I could not find `nowox`

```
grep -r nowox
```

Any idea?

Comment: See a wide range of answers (the right one depends on your OS) at https://stackoverflow.com/q/35942754/1256452

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `git config credential.helper` output

If the helper is caching the wrong credentials, force it to ask you again said credentials with (as explained in "[How do I sign out in the Git Bash console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)")

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com
```