# Trying to upload a project to github through command line but it says PERMISSION TO [old account name] denied

Tags: git, github, command-line, git-bash

I am trying to upload a project to github so I ran the command

```
$ git push origin master
```

but it gives me

```
remmote: Permission to [repo name] denied to [old github account I used on this 
laptop]

fatal: unable to access repository
```

Answer (score 1):

You need first to check the remote URL used:

```
git remote -v
```

If it starts with https://, you might have a cache with the wrong credentials in it

```
git config credential.helper
```

For instance, see "[sign out in the Git Bash console in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)":

```
git credential-manager reject https://github.com
```

On Mac, for `osxkeychain`, see "[Updating credentials from the OSX Keychain](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain)"

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase https://github.com
```

Then the next push would trigger a popup asking you to enter the username/password.

---

If it starts with `git@github.com:...`, you might use the default id_rsa private key for the old account.

Comment: DO I type $git remote -v?

Comment: @ckaepie no need for the $ (prompt sign): just `git remote -v` in the folder where your repository is (where you typed `git push` before)

Comment: It is giving me this: fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: If you were able to type `git push` before, you should type it in the same spot. It should be in the root folder of your local repository, where you can see a `.git/` subfolder.

Comment: ok I see it thank you for the next command do I enter my old account girhub url or do I just write https://github.com

Comment: When I try to do git credential-manager reject it gives me this: fatal: InvalidOperationException encountered.
   Invalid input, please see 'https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-credential.html'.

Comment: @ckaepie It depends on the result of `git config credential.helper`

Comment: @ckaepie I have to go, but I'll check in in a few hours. Leave the output of `git config credential.helper` as well as `git version` and your OS.

Comment: It says MANAGER.  OS: Windows 10. Git Version: 2.25.0.windows.1

Comment: Then the reject should work, with https://github.com at the end.

Comment: It must be another problem because I went in my control panel -> credentials and my github credential was correct to my current account. Must be another problem :/

Comment: Then what is the remote url you are working with? What is the output of git remote -v?