# Two github accounts conflicting on the same computer

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, version-control

I have 2 github accounts, one for personal use and one for work.

I am working on a personal website and so I have logged into git from the terminal using my personal username and password. When I do a 'git config --list' I am shown the correct username and password for my personal account as I would expect.

However when I then try and push my code up to my personal account it gives this error...

```
remote: Permission to <personal_username>/<personal_repo>.git denied to <work_username>.
```

I have no idea where it is even picking up my work username or work credentials from as they are not listed in my git config.

Please help!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using HTTPS or SSH for your repositories?

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is an HTTPS one, check your `git config credential.helper`: if manager, if would have cached, you need to [reject its URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38553149/6309)

```
git credential-manager reject 
protocol=https
host=github.com
```

Comment: Where do I put that code sorry? I've run a 'git config -l' and my work credentials aren't even showing there so I don't know where the computer is picking them up from anymore

Comment: @brianmcgowan credentials have nothing to do with git config. That command is to be typed in a bash or CMD, then you type `protocol=...` and `host=...`. What OS are you on? With which version of Git?

Comment: git version 2.17.2 (Apple Git-113) and I am using a Mac

Comment: @brianmcgowan OK. Could you upgrade to 2.27?